# Simple homepage featured products listing in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

Im trying to implement a simple products list to show at the homepage and every single solution i've found on the web fails in my setup (Magento 1.9.0.1). It seems that most articles are only relevant to previous versions.

Anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

See also https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9  - good idea to create a custom template file to call.

Comment: Im gonna take this as the correct answer although i can't get it to work. It always lists only one product but I know suspect something's broken with my Magento install. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Actually, after further testing I've confirmed this to be a bug in the new RWD theme.

Comment: is there any solution or is the RWD theme just buggy?

Answer (score 2):

Just spent a few hours trying to figure this out.

Follow the guide here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9

We did this but then the page simply said that no products could be found. You'll need to add `column_count="10"` (or however many you want) to the block call in the CMS, and also make sure that the category you're referencing by ID is a sub-category of the main "Default" category or again it won't return any results.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For displaying featured products in the homepage please create featured attribute field in the backend.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/adding-custom-product-attributes-in-magento/

Please step my code for step by step explanation.

Then you can retrieve the products in the homepage phtml using the following code.

```
<?php
$featuredProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',4)
->addAttributeToFilter('featured_product', 1);
?>
```