# Show products on page on magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I read this question and it didn't work for me: [Magento - How to display ALL PRODUCTS in the homepage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253389/magento-how-to-display-all-products-in-the-homepage)

It says: "there are no products matching the selection"

I have my product in the root catalog.

This is my product:
[image]

And the code I'm using is:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: have you tried this code `{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="<root-cat-id>" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

Comment: have you assign it to root category?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal It still says:"there are no products matching the selection"

Comment: check this [answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/20996/4426). might be helpful. ([this comment too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894386/simple-homepage-featured-products-listing-in-magento-1-9#comment36790006_23894809))

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I'm not getting the error the OP got though.

Answer (score 1):

You missing this sentence from reference.
You could also use the same code to drill down into a specific category, by adding the category variable, e.g.

Create one category on admin side and Include in Navigation Menu => No,
and select "Category Products" to select all product and Save category.

Remove old code 
Then use this code 
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="your cat. id previously you created " template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}